# Selenium Tests: Authenticate with Webauthn

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, webauthn

In my use case, there is a registration page that triggers the browser-specific webauthn flow. For example in Chrome on a Mac you will see this series of popups:

1. Pick an option between USB security key and Built-in sensor
2. MacOS confirmation with Touch ID
3. Confirmation dialog from Chrome requesting access to your security key

Besides https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#add-virtual-authenticator I haven't found much documentation about authenticating with webauthn as part of a selenium test. **What resources are available to help devs figure out how to test webauthn with Selenium in JavaScript?** I have also checked out https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7829 but the example test case does not make sense to me. Examples would be **hugely** appreciated.

**Update with solution for js**:

```
  import { Command } from 'selenium-webdriver/lib/command';

  addVirtualAuthenticator = async () => {
    await this.driver.getSession().then(async session => {
      this.driver
        .getExecutor()
        .defineCommand('AddVirtualAuthenticator', 'POST', `/session/${session.id_}/webauthn/authenticator`);

      let addVirtualAuthCommand = new Command('AddVirtualAuthenticator');
      addVirtualAuthCommand.setParameter('protocol', 'ctap2');
      addVirtualAuthCommand.setParameter('transport', 'internal');
      addVirtualAuthCommand.setParameter('hasResidentKey', true);
      addVirtualAuthCommand.setParameter('isUserConsenting', true);
      await this.driver.getExecutor().execute(addVirtualAuthCommand);
    });
  };
```

Note that `this.driver` is of type `WebDriver`.

Call `addVirtualAuthenticator` before hitting any code that interacts with `navigator` (in our case user registration involved a call to `navigator.credentials.create`). If you need access to the publicKey, i.e. via `navigator.credentials.get({ publicKey: options })` during login, then `hasResidentKey` is **critical**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good resource for an example if you're implementing this in java and using selenium 4 is [the tests on selenium itself](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/941dc9c6b2e2aa4f701c1b72be8de03d4b7e996a/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/virtualauthenticator/VirtualAuthenticatorTest.java). You basically need to

- Create a virtual authenticator

  In your case, you should set the transport to `internal` and hasUserVerification to `true` to simulate touchID.

```java
VirtualAuthenticatorOptions options = new VirtualAuthenticatorOptions();
options.setTransport(Transport.INTERNAL)
       .hasUserVerification(true)
       .isUserVerified(true);
VirtualAuthenticator authenticator =
    ((HasVirtualAuthenticator) driver).addVirtualAuthenticator(options);
```

- Perform the action that triggers registration.

  If everything goes right, the browser should not show a dialog. Instead, it should immediately return a credential.

For any other language or selenium version, you will need to drop into calling the WebDriver protocol directly. As you pointed out, the [W3C spec has documentation on the protocol endpoints](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#sctn-automation).

For java, it might be something like

```java
browser.driver.getExecutor().defineCommand(
    "AddVirtualAuthenticator", "POST", "/session/:sessionId/webauthn/authenticator");

// ...

Command addVirtualAuthCommand = new Command("AddVirtualAuthenticator");
addVirtualAuthCommand.setParameter("protocol", "ctap2");
addVirtualAuthCommand.setParameter("transport", "usb");
browser.driver.getExecutor().execute(addVirtualAuthCommand);
```

For javascript, you should be able to use [defineCommand](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/http_exports_Executor.html#defineCommand) and [webDriver.execute](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebDriver.html) in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful info! I was able to get registration working with a javascript-ified version of the sample java code you provided. Interestingly, although registration works, attempting to subsequently login with the newly created account fails, pointing me towards https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#sctn-privacy-considerations-client. I am still debugging this and will give an update when I know more. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It's possible the authenticator is being created for a different frame than the one you're trying to assert from. This happens if you are trying to exercise the credential from a different frame tree (e.g. from another browser instance, or from a parent iframe). What happens if you call the GetCredentials command?

Comment: Ahhh I could see that being the problem. Calling GetCredentials from the tests returns an empty array. Investigating more today.

Comment: Aha! On login, the UI is calling `navigator.credentials.get({ publicKey: options })`, so for the virtual authenticator to work I needed to include `addVirtualAuthCommand.setParameter('hasResidentKey', true);` Such a simple fix, so long to figure it out. But it works now!  Still sorting out the test structure, so I'll update with more complete findings once I'm happy with that.

Comment: Thanks @NinaSatragno for your awesome contributions in this regard :)

Answer (score -2):

This is worst practice in selenium

> Two Factor Authentication shortly know as 2FA is a authorization
> mechanism where One Time Password(OTP) is generated using
> “Authenticator” mobile apps such as “Google Authenticator”, “Microsoft
> Authenticator” etc., or by SMS, e-mail to authenticate. Automating
> this seamlessly and consistently is a big challenge in Selenium. There
> are some ways to automate this process. But that will be another layer
> on top of our Selenium tests and not secured as well. So, you can
> avoid automating 2FA.

There are few options to get around 2FA checks:

1.Disable 2FA for certain Users in the test environment, so that you can use those user credentials in the automation.
2.Disable 2FA in your test environment.
3.Disable 2FA if you login from certain IPs. That way we can configure our test machine IPs to avoid this.

Comment: The question is about WebAuthn (not authenticator apps), for which selenium 4+ has support. You may also want to test the 2FA as part of your E2E suite.