# Windows WebAuthn API failed to load

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, visual-studio-code

I started using selenium to scrape website but it says Windows WebAuthn Api failed to load. how to fix it? Please help! thank you!

[image: Here is the image]

This error is causing my selenium webdriver to close instantly. Here is my little piece of code
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to test it in a system terminal outside of VS Code?

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I've run the same code in vs code on ubuntu during development and it works fine. But when I compiled the program on windows and run it on windows 8.1  I'm now getting this kind of error.

Comment: @IceBear i found out though it throws the error but it doesn't really affect the functioning of the program so I am ignoring the error

Comment: @Ishan Bhardwaj what's the version of your windows?

Comment: @Steven it is windows 8

Comment: @ It needs Windows10. You can refer to the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/webauthnapis)

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63477115/selenium-tests-authenticate-with-webauthn